# Renderizar imagem no display gráfico

Tags: imagem, arduino, display

Programa para IDE arduino, ESP32.
Objetivo é ter duas funções para renderizar no display gráfico, o logotipo, imagem previamente estática na memoria FLASH ou imagem predefinida via UPLOAD.

A função drawBitmap, funciona como esperado, lê um arquivo armazenado na FLASH e renderiza corretamente na tela.

```
//chamada drawBitmap(0,0,logow81h25branco, 81, 25,TFT_RED);
void drawBitmap(int x, int y, const uint16_t* bitmap, int bw, int bh,uint16_t color_bg) {

   int register buffidx = 0;
   int register row;
   int register col;
   int w = bw + y;
   int h = bh + x;

     for (row = x; row < h; row++) { // For each scanline...
          for (col = y; col < w; col++) { // For each pixel...
              //To read from Flash Memory, pgm_read_XXX is required.
              //Since image is stored as uint16_t, pgm_read_word is used as it uses 16bit address

            uint16_t color = pgm_read_word(bitmap + buffidx);
            if(color_bg != color)tft.drawPixel(col, row, color);   //pixel só cores diferente do fundo  
            buffidx++;
         } // end pixel
      }
    } // drawBitmap
```

A função drawlogo tem objetivo de lê um arquivo que foi UPLOAD anteriormente. Foi substituído a instrução "pgm_read_word" por "word(FileRead.read(),FileRead.read())" porém, apesar sem erros, renderiza errado na tela.
O conteúdo do arquivo, é idêntico ao arquivo da memoria FLASH.

```
void drawlogo(int x, int y, int bw, int bh,uint16_t color_bg)
{
     int register row;
     int register col;
     int w = bw + y;
     int h = bh + x;

     if (SPIFFS.exists("/data/logoinicial.txt")) { //lê logotipo em formato 16bits

      File FileRead = SPIFFS.open("/data/logoinicial.txt", "r");
       while (FileRead.available() > 0) {
          for (row = x; row < h; row++) { // For each scanline...
            for (col = y; col < w; col++) { // For each pixel...
                                        
              uint16_t color = word(FileRead.read(),FileRead.read());//lê 2 byte

              if(color_bg != color)tft.drawPixel(col, row, color); //pixel só cores diferente do fundo  
              
     } // end pixel
    } //end scanline
   }//while   
  FileRead.close();       
 }//SPIFFS.exists                    
}//void drawlogo
```

A imagem BMP está convertida em dados de 16bits, através do software LCD Image Converter  [http://www.riuson.com/lcd-image-converter] e referenciada no código como abaixo

```
const uint16_t logow81h25branco[6075] PROGMEM = {
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0xffff, 0xffff, 
 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 
 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98, 0x3b98
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece um problema de [`Undefined behavior`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) nessa linha

```
uint16_t color = word(FileRead.read(),FileRead.read());//lê 2 byte
```

Se você deixar definida a ordem da leitura via código provavelmente resolvera o problema.

```
byte b1 = FileRead.read();
byte b2 = FileRead.read();
uint16_t color = word(b1, b2);
```